# Rails 4 routing in rspec for testing PATCH

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, ruby-on-rails-4

This is my `routes.rb`

```
resources :agreements, param: :customer_number, only: :show, as: 'agreement_from_customer_number'

resources :agreements, only: [:index, :update] do
   resources :orders, only: :index
end
```

This is my `AgreementsController`

```
def update
   ...
end
```

And this is my rspec test for testing the update action:

```
before :each do
  @agreement = create :agreement
end

it 'updates the correct agreement through the internal API' do
    patch agreement_path(@agreement)
end
```

My application uses `ActiveModel`, so it has no database. Because of this, the `create`method in the `before` block simply does the following:

`factories/agreement.rb`

```
factory :agreement do
  skip_create
  id '1'
  customer_number '1001'
  agreement_id '101'
  return_address 'Fakeville, USA'
  return_postal_code '2013'
end
```

The test returns the following error:

```
ActionController::UrlGenerationError:
   No route matches {:id=>#<Agreement:0x007f94ab7b0ce0 @id="1", @agreement_id="101", @customer_number="1001", @return_address="Fakeville, USA", @return_postal_code="2013">} missing required keys: [:id]
```

And if I change the test to look like this:

```
it 'updates the correct agreement through the internal API' do
    patch agreement_path(@agreement.id)
end
```

I get the following error:

```
     ActionController::UrlGenerationError:
   No route matches {:controller=>"agreements", :action=>"/agreements/1"}
```

Help :-|

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this particular problem by doing the following:

`patch :update, agreement: @agreement.attributes`

Because the controller expects a hash of values rather than an object literal, this worked :-)